# Sitecore Content Editor throws : Server Error in '/' Application error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-management-system, sitecore9

When I try to Open the content editor in Sitecore 9.1 it throws the following error.
This is the link to the stack trace :

[image: stack trace]

please help me out in resolving this error.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception Details**: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> **Source Error**: An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> **Stack Trace:** [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
>      Sitecore.Buckets.Commands.MakeTemplateBucketable.GetToolTip(CommandContext context, String tooltip) +167
>      Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.FillParamsFromCommand(CommandContext commandContext, RibbonCommandParams ribbonCommandParams) +186
>      Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.GetCommandParameters(Item controlItem, CommandContext commandContext) +78
>      Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderSmallCheckButton(HtmlTextWriter output, Item button, CommandContext commandContext) +99
>      Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderButton(HtmlTextWriter output, Item button, CommandContext commandContext) +823
>      Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderChunk(HtmlTextWriter output, Item chunk, CommandContext commandContext) +341
>      Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderChunk(HtmlTextWriter output, Item chunk, CommandContext commandContext, Boolean isContextual, String id) +243
>      Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderChunk(HtmlTextWriter output, Item chunk, CommandContext commandContext, Boolean isContextual) +160
>      Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderChunks(HtmlTextWriter output, Item strip, CommandContext commandContext, Boolean isContextual) +425
>      Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderStrips(HtmlTextWriter output, Item ribbon, Boolean isContextual, ListString visibleStripList) +1612
>      Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderStrips(HtmlTextWriter output, Item defaultRibbon, Item contextualRibbon, ListString visibleStripList) +161
>      Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.Render(HtmlTextWriter output) +733
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +131
>      Sitecore.Web.HtmlUtil.RenderControl(Control ctl) +79
>      Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.UpdateRibbon(Item folder, Boolean isCurrentItemChanged, Boolean showEditor) +559
>      Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.Update() +581
>      Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.OnPreRendered(EventArgs e) +204
>   [TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
>      System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
>      System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +128
>      System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +142
>      Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj) +89
>      Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +143
>      System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +200
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +7479

Comment: Welcome to SO, please consider elaborating your question. Posting a error trace is a bad practice. Please, follow https://stackoverflow.com/tour and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how to make high quality questions.

Comment: The error turns up just when i try to open the content editor .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just got the same error. This seems to happen when the template of an item you are trying to open is broken. In your case you probably broke the Home Item, which is automatically selected when you open the content editor. To verify, you can rename the home item in the DBBrowser (so that it is not selected automatically). Afterwards the content editor should work again and you should see a broken link warning in the quick action bar.

Easiest way to fix is probably:

- Create a package of the complete template hierarchy of your home item
- Install that package

Afterwards you should be able to re-rename you home item and start the Content Editor normally.